# Regex to match part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex fun again...

Take for example http://something.com/en/page

I want to test for an exact match on /en/ including the forward slashes, otherwise it could match 'en' from other parts of the string.

I'm sure this is easy, for someone other than me!

EDIT:

I'm using it for a string.match() in javascript

Comment: For which programming language do you need the regex? C# and VB.net, for example both understand `"/en/"`, but this is obviously not what you are looking for...

Comment: @Heinzi - JavaScript has a shorthand way of defining a regex, e.g. var someRegex = /\/en\//ig which can also be written like this var someRegex = new RegExp("/en/", "ig"). Generally the shorthand way is preferred. I only ever use new RegExp if I need to build the regex by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it really depends on what programming language will be executing the regex, but the actual regex is simply

```
/en/
```

For .Net the following code works properly:

```
string url = "http://something.com/en/page";

bool MatchFound = Regex.Match(url, "/en/").Success;
```

Here is the JavaScript version:

```
var url = 'http://something.com/en/page';
if (url.match(/\/en\//)) {
    alert('match found');
}
else {
    alert('no match');
}
```

**DUH**

Thank you to Welbog and Chris Ballance to making what should have been the most obvious point.  This does not require Regular Expressions to solve.  It simply is a contains statement.  Regex should only be used where it is needed and that should have been my first consideration and not the last.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.. I was having problems with escaping my slashes.

Comment: Using `regex.test()` is less costly than `string.match()`

Comment: Using a simple String.Contains("/en/") is less costly than using a Regex at all...

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to match `/en/` specifically, you don't need a regular expression at all. Just use your language's equivalent of `contains` to test for that substring.

If you're trying to match any two-letter part of the URL between two slashes, you need an expression like this:

```
/../
```

If you want to capture the two-letter code, enclose the periods in parentheses:

```
/(..)/
```

Depending on your language, you may need to escape the slashes:

```
\/..\/
\/(..)\/
```

And if you want to make sure you match letters instead of any character (including numbers and symbols), you might want to use an expression like this instead:

```
/[a-z]{2}/
```

Which will be recognized by most regex variations.

Again, you can escape the slashes and add a capturing group this way:

```
\/([a-z]{2})\/
```

And if you don't need to escape them:

```
 /([a-z]{2})/
```

This expression will match any string in the form `/xy/` where `x` and `y` are letters. So it will match `/en/`, `/fr/`, `/de/`, etc.

In JavaScript, you'll need the escaped version: `\/([a-z]{2})\/`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that Regexps are not necessary for exact matches.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to escape the forward-slashes...

```
/\/en\//
```

Comment: Just do a string match, Regex is overkill for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason `/en/` would not work?

Comment: It would not work since the slash is integral part of the regex hence the need to escape it as per Parappa's answer as the slash is used as an indicator in regex generally, on most posix compliant systems such as unix, there would be extra info supplied, for example to search for a string ignoring upper/lower case would be /some_string/i.

Comment: And also it is based on what programming language, see TheLameDuck's answer. Definitely for C#, you would need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: Though I appreciate the kudos, it is only the backslash \ that would need to be escaped.

Plus, you could always sidestep the whole issue if there were an issue by making it a string literal, ie string test = #"my back \ slash";

Comment: What? No. No need to escape the *forward* slash in a C# string.

Comment: I just saw a typo in my comment.  It should have been: string test = @"my back \ slash";

Comment: This is not a Regex, just a standard string match.

Answer (score 0):

`/\/en\//` or perhaps `/http\w*:\/\/[^\/]*\/en\//`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
location.pathname.substr(0, 4) === "/en/"
```

Of course, if you insist on using a regex, use this:

```
/^\/en\//.test(location.pathname)
```